# Visual Studio Code to recognize the __fastcall convention

Tags: c++, delphi, visual-studio-code, c++builder

I am working on a C++ project written in Embarcadero C++Builder (as it has legacy support for Delphi components).

As far as I know, there aren't any other IDEs that can build these types of projects, but the editor is just horrible there, so I want to write code using VSCode (and build using the regular IDE).

I've managed to get the right include paths working, so that there are no include errors shown for now.

Currently, I'm dealing with an error where it doesn't recognize the `__fastcall` calling convention, simply calling it an "incomplete type".

Yes, I know I won't get a perfect developing experience, but are there any workarounds to configure VSCode to avoid errors such as this?

Comment: I assume you are talking about c++ intellisense errors, you probably need to adjust your `c_cpp_properties.json`. There is some documentation here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations)

Comment: What compiler are you using in VS Code? AFAIK, *most* Windows-compatible compliers support the `__fastcall` keyword/convention. But, I suppose, if yours *doesn't*, then you could #define it somewhere (to be nothing), if you're not going to actual use the system to build your final product.

Comment: VSC is a <expletive deleted> to configure if you don't know what you are doing (and I'm in that camp, unfortunately) but it's really versatile. Worth seeing if someone has a recipe you can use or adapt for making it use the Embarcadero tools directly and cut C++ builder right out of the chain.

Comment: @Adrian Mole I am planning on switching to CLang from Embercadero's default compiler. Haven't switched yet but I'm guessing to avoid intellisense errors I should point my compiler path to it? Because the "Compiler" is set to CLangx86 by default in VSCode which doesn't seem to affect the errors as I don't have it installed yet

Comment: @AdrianMole "*AFAIK, most Windows-compatible compliers support the `__fastcall` keyword/convention*" - Embarcadero inherited the old Borland C++ compilers, and then added their own CLang-based compilers. Borland's flavor of `__fastcall` (which is what Delphi uses) is different than Microsoft's flavor (MS's flavor is `__msfastcall` in Borland/Embarcadero's compilers).  No 3rd party compiler implements Borland's flavor of `__fastcall`, AFAIK.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't know that. I used Embarcadero for a while (until my free licence ran out) but I was using the clang compiler in it, anyway. But, even so, I don't get why the OP's VSC compiler doesn't recognize the `__fastcall` keyword - even if it gets it wrong.

Comment: @KapitaiN I am not familiar with VSCode, does it allow you to use a 3rd party command-line compiler?  If so, why not have it use [Embarcadero's command-line compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Command-Line_Interfaces_of_C%2B%2B_Compilers) (bcc32.exe, bcc32c.exe, bcc32x.exe, bcc64.exe, etc)?

Comment: Possibly related: [__cdecl and 5 other keywords aren't recognized by IntelliSense with clang without -fms-extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3296): "*The symptoms here appears to specific to clang-x86 on Linux and Mac. These keywords are not accepted by clang when building for x64 on Linux and Mac (compilation fails). **On Windows, these are all supported properly for both clang and clang-cl and both x86 and x64, as a result of cpptools always providing -ms_extensions to the IntelliSense process**.*"  Maybe you are missing that latter step in your config?

Comment: Ok an update. After setting the path to bcc32c.exe and setting the compiler as ${default} it seems to have fixed most of the errors however I can still see some of the include erros for example by .hpp files which are Pascal files on the local machine. Idk if there's a way to fix this